# CPU usage away from normal on Ubuntu 20.04 (Reaching 97%)

Tags: 20.04, cpu

I want to ask a question, hope somebody here can answer mine.
I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T40 with Ubuntu 20.04. For the begining, it was normal, but time by time, there is a problem. My CPU usage (one core) is reaching 97% usage. I dont open any heavy apps. I just open my vscode, but the CPU Usage reaching 97%. Please help me.
Thank you for your attention.
[Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaU9q.png)
[Resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je1LL.png)

Comment: try monotiring process as root from htop. or observer the behaviour from live cd and don't forget to have up-to-date software

Comment: I must admit that looks weird enough I wonder if the system monitor is wrong? Is the machine having to constantly run a cooling fan, or seem at all sluggish? the Processes tab looks perfectly normal. As mentioned try verifying the problem, open a terminal and run:    top

Comment: when i launch "top" command, i get kworker+ running on 84,7% CPU usage. My fan is active and the wind feels hot. I think there is a problem with it